# Excel macro runs in console and through debugger, but not with button

Tags: excel, vba

**Error / Expected Output**
When I run it from the VBA console, the code executes properly. If I step through the code manually in the debugger, it works.

The expected output is the ID of about 2000 data points. I am checking if a data matches the user input date. If that is the case, I print the ID of the event on the other sheet. Ideally, I will have a list of inputs that have numerical IDs.

When I run the code from the console or debugger, I will get a range of IDs like: 1,2,4,5,6,11,14,166... However, when I run this from the button I consistently get the first two data points, no matter which field (Date, Time, Size).

If I set a break point in the debugger then hit the button, the code is fine. All I have to do is hold run (F5). I think this tells me that the code compiles and works; meaning that the error is not a compile or logic error.

**Goal**
I would like the button to run the code normally.

**More Info**
I set a break point at every iteration of each loop. I held the step in key. The code ran flawlessly. This worked for both the console window, and the button.

Because of this, I thought I was experiencing an error due to race conditions. I went on to run the *doEvents* command. I was given the same results. The console and debugger ran the code properly, but the button did not.

**The Code**

```
Sub ThisBookSource()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Start = Now()
    Dim masterRow As Integer
    Dim myEvents
    masterRow = 9
    masterRow2 = 9

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graphs by Source").Activate
    myCode = Range("D" & "2").Value
    Range("C9:C2290").Clear
    Range("T9:U2290").Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Activate

    For I = 3 To 2113
        If Range("T" & I) = myCode Then
            Worksheets("Data").Range("M" & I).Copy
            Worksheets("Graphs by Source").Range("C" & masterRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            masterRow = masterRow + 1
            If I Mod 250 = 0 Then
                DoEvents
            End If
        End If
    Next I
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graphs by Source").Activate
    Calculate

    For I = 9 To 2290
        If Range("I" & I).Value <> "NA" Then
            Range("T" & masterRow2) = Range("G" & I).Value
            Range("U" & masterRow2) = Range("I" & I).Value
            masterRow2 = masterRow2 + 1
            If I Mod 250 = 0 Then
                DoEvents
            End If
        End If
    Next I

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    MsgBox "Done. Started at " & Start & ", and ended at " & Now & "!"
End Sub
```

**Note**
I cannot post screen shots because the data is sensitive and confidential.

Comment: ...What's the problem with the code?  You should also be explicitly referencing the worksheet on all `Range()` and `Cells() `calls.

Comment: @BruceWayne I will add direct references (book --> sheet --> range), and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Jsleshem I feel like you are attempting to provide a detailed question, but you are still being very vague with **what's not working**. Are you getting an error message? What is the expected result, and what is the current behavior?

Comment: @all, I made some updates. Specifically, check the error section

Comment: @dwirony I added an better output section. Also, there are no errors, the code is just producing different results based on where it is being run from.

Comment: There's no need for `masterRow` and `masterRow2`. They're used in different loops. Just reset the value of `masterRow` after your first loop, use it in the 2nd loop, and delete `Dim masterRow2...`

Comment: Comment out the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` until you have it working. That's probably hiding an error of some sort (like changing worksheets) from you.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of `myCode = Range("D" & "2").Value`? You can just write `myCode = Range("D2").Value`. Seeing that leads me to believe that there was a variable being used in there before someone replaced it with a constant.

Comment: @FreeMan arguably that's giving another meaning to a variable, a practice that makes me cringe. A much better option would be to refactor this monster into multiple, smaller, more specialized procedures.

Comment: arguably, @Mat'sMug, but it could just as easily be renamed `currentRow` which would be quite applicable for both loops. Yes, refactoring would be a better bet in the long run, though. As would eliminating all the implicit `ActiveSheet` references, uses of `Range.Copy`/`Range.Paste`, etc. But, this is [SO], not [CodeReview.SE]...

Comment: @Mat'sMug Can you explain why having explicit object calls would be better than implicit in this case? I am confused on why that would make such a difference.

Comment: If you mean to work with `ThisWorkbook`, work with `ThisWorkbook`. Doing `Range("foobar")` works off `ActiveSheet`, which **may or may not be** a worksheet in `ThisWorkbook` - it's a worksheet in *whatever workbook is currently active*. It makes the whole difference. And causes bugs that make a new SO question asked, every single day. Rule of thumb, explicit *anything* is better than implicit *whatever* in VBA. The language is already doing way too much stuff behind your back, you need to take control.

Comment: @Mat'sMug post your comment as an answer, that made it work!!!! Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean to work with `ThisWorkbook`, work with `ThisWorkbook`. Doing `Range("foobar")` [implicitly] works off `ActiveSheet`, which *may or may not* be a worksheet in `ThisWorkbook` - it's a worksheet in *whatever workbook is currently active*. It makes the whole difference. And causes bugs every day.

Rule of thumb, explicit anything is better than implicit whatever in VBA. The language is already doing way too much stuff behind your back, you need to take control.

[Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (open-source VBE add-in project I manage) can help you find all instances of implicit `ActiveSheet` references... and many other potential issues.